# Converting DateTime format to be readable without converting to a varchar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, telerik, radgrid

In my RadGrid my date is displayed like this:

```
AUG-14 1:57:00 PM-01
```

(Maybe becuase the web page is right to left)
when it should look like this:

```
2014-08-01 13:57:00
```

(This is how it looks in the Database when selected)
The reason I cannot convert it is because I need the sorting option, the sorting won't work well if it is not of DateTime Format.

Comment: First of all, `DateTime` doesn't have any implicit format. `Strings` have. Second, did you try anything to solve your problem? I feel you just need to format of your RadGrid column which you bind your `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To format a date inside a Radgrid, try using the `DataFormatString`

```
<MasterTableView>                                                         
    <Columns>                                    
        <radG:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="My Date Field" 
            DataField ="myDateField" 
            DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"></radG:GridBoundColumn>  
     </Columns>                                                    
 </MasterTableView>
```

Comment: Thank you, works great, but my date is a key field in my db and i sometimes use it to find values, like so (WHERE updatedate = ValueFromSelectedGrid), but the value is now formatted, How can i get the value as it was before the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

where `dt` is the time you read from the database.